# Storing / Retrieving Images with Access & VB.NET 2012

Tags: vb.net, image, ms-access

VB.NET 2012

I have an image, an mdb file, and a headache...

I've created a table that will have a path field, name field, and object field to store an image in Access. Easy enough to execute:

```
CREATE TABLE DATATABLE (FilePath CHAR, FileName CHAR, FileObject LONGBINARY)
```

My problem now? SOMEHOW getting an image into, and out of, that table. This seems like it should be easily done - but I've been banging my head on the table with outdated Append/GetChunk methods, WriteBLOBToFile methods that don't work, and everything else. Google is usually my friend, but today I'm getting help that just doesn't work.

Anyone out there have a way to get an image into, and out of, the above-mentioned table? This really seems like it should be straight-forward.

And please - as much as I'd rather store the images in the file system rather than this, the specs are calling for image storage in Access. No way around it. Thanks for any help on this!!!

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: If the column is OLEObject, you can simply use a memorystream to save the image.  When you read it, it comes back as Byte() from which a tidy temp new MemoryStream can be created until the actual image is needed.

Comment: You mention an .mdb file, not an .accdb file. Do you need to insert the image in such a way that it can be used by older versions of the Access application itself? (That is, does it need to be stored as an OLE Object instead of just the raw image bytes?)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can use a `MemoryStream` as an intermediary if you don't need to store the data such that it can be accessed as an image in Access.

```
Private Sub SaveImage(picture As Image, id As Integer)
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("connection string here")
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE MyTable SET Picture = @Picture WHERE ID = @ID", connection)

    'Create an empty stream in memory.
    Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream
        'Fill the stream with the binary data from the Image.
        picture.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

        'Get an array of Bytes from the stream and assign to the parameter.
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", stream.GetBuffer())
    End Using

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id)

    connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
End Sub

Private Function LoadImage(id As Integer) As Image
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("connection string here")
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Picture FROM MyTable WHERE ID = @ID", connection)

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id)

    connection.Open()

    Dim pictureData As Byte() = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

    connection.Close()

    Dim picture As Image

    'Create a stream in memory containing the bytes that comprise the image.
    Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream(pictureData)
        'Read the stream and create an Image object from the data.
        picture = Image.FromStream(stream)
    End Using

    Return picture
End Function
```