# Error no values given to one or more of Parameters

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Okay so whenever i trying to insert data into my access database its not working...

The error say that no value given...

This is my code

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class halaman_daftar_anggota
Dim Conn As OleDbConnection
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim CMD As OleDbCommand

Dim LokasiDB As String
Sub Koneksi()
    LokasiDB = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=perpustakaan.accdb"
    Conn = New OleDbConnection(LokasiDB)
    If Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then Conn.Open()
End Sub
Private Sub halaman_daftar_anggota_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Koneksi()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from data_anggota", Conn)
    ds = New DataSet
    ds.Clear()
    da.Fill(ds, "data_anggota")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dialog As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

    dialog.Title = "Browse Foto"
    dialog.Filter = "image files(*.png; *.bmp; *.jpg;*.jpeg; *.gif; |*.png; *.bmp; *.jpg;*.jpeg; *.gif;)"
    If dialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dialog.FileName)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim simpan As String = "INSERT INTO data_anggota (nomor_induk,nama_siswa,kelas_siswa,nomor_anggota,foto) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "',@image)"
    Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream()
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Dim data As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
    Dim p As New OleDbParameter("@image", OleDbType.LongVarBinary)
    p.Value = data
    CMD = New OleDbCommand(simpan, Conn)
    CMD.ExecuteNonQuery() <- the error located
    MsgBox("Berhasil")
End Sub
```

My guess is the image wont inserted. (the foto is ole object in database) but considering im an absolute novice in this so i cant really tell....

Comment: Haven't you already asked this question? You're still not adding the Parameter to the Command. Also, use Parameters to add all the other values in the query. AKA, do not concatenate strings. -- All the other issues are still not resolved (starting from `Dim Conn As OleDbConnection`: don't do that).

Comment: Alright sir i try my best... Sorry for the trouble...

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156416/how-to-insert-image-to-access-database-oleobject-field and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336058/storing-retrieving-images-with-access-vb-net-2012

Comment: Thank you sir jimi and sir june7 for helping me... Sorry for disturbing you sir. Too bad i cant give answer to an comment.... Once again im very grateful. I manahge to add parameters and repair my sorry statr of a code and it works... Thank you and sorry for disturbing yoi guys